# Annotate several Fields at once in JavaFX

Tags: annotations, javafx

Is it possible to annotate several fields with one annotation? Something like:

```
@FXML(
private TextField tf1;
private TextField tf2;
private TextField tf3;)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot annotate several fields with one annotation.

Comment: A pity :) Thank you for the answer anyway